# Merge a sub document to main document with mongodb aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is a sample record of my collection:

```
{
    _id:someId,
    pages:[
     {id:id,field:value},
     {id:otherId,field:otherValue}
    ]

}
```

Here is what I am doing:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$pages"}
])
```

And its result is similar to:

```
{
  _id:id,
  pages:{id:id,field:value}  
},
{
  _id:id,
  pages:{id:otherId,field:otherValue}
}
```

However, what I wanna achieve is:

```
{
    _id:id,
    id:id,
    field:value
},
{
    _id:id,
    id:otherId,
    field:otherValue
}
```

Can I do something with `$project` operation to merge sub document into the main document?

Comment: The result you have listed as your desired output is not formatted correctly. I wouldn't know how to achieve it.

Comment: @Tiramisu i updated the format

Comment: Add `{ "$project": { "id": "$pages.id", "field": "$pages.field" } }` to your pipeline after `$unwind`ing the array.

Comment: There's no way currently to do that without a $project stage, but in this case they won't cost too much, so go for this solution.

Comment: @user3100115 i thought about that but the problem is i dont have just 2 fields as here i have about 10 fields in your case i should write everything one by one anyway that seems the only way please write this as an answer so i can accept that as the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reshape your documents, you need to add a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to your pipeline and use the [*dot notation*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to access the sub-documents' fields.

```
{ "$project": { "id": "$pages.id", "field": "$pages.field" } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach which is some what closer to your expected result.

My Sample Data

```
  "_id" : 1,
  "pages" : [
          {
                  "_id" : "a",
                  "comment" : "Have a Nice Day"
          },
          {
                  "_id" : "b",
                  "comment" : "Everyday is Beautiful"
          },
          {
                  "_id" : "c",
                  "comment" : "All is Well"
          },
          {
                  "_id" : "d",
                  "comment" : "Nature is wonderful"
          },
          {
                  "_id" : "e",
                  "comment" : "Enjoy the moment"
          }
  ]
```

After executing `db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$pages"}])`

```
"_id" : 1, "pages" : { "_id" : "a", "comment" : "Have a Nice Day" } }
"_id" : 1, "pages" : { "_id" : "b", "comment" : "Everyday is Beautiful" } }
"_id" : 1, "pages" : { "_id" : "c", "comment" : "All is Well" } }
"_id" : 1, "pages" : { "_id" : "d", "comment" : "Nature is wonderful" } }
"_id" : 1, "pages" : { "_id" : "e", "comment" : "Enjoy the moment" } }
```

then added $group into the pipeline

`db.collectiom.aggregate([{$unwind:"$pages"}, {$group:{_id:"$pages"}}]);`

```
"_id" : { "_id" : "e", "comment" : "Enjoy the moment" } }
"_id" : { "_id" : "d", "comment" : "Nature is wonderful" } }
"_id" : { "_id" : "c", "comment" : "All is Well" } }
"_id" : { "_id" : "b", "comment" : "Everyday is Beautiful" } }
"_id" : { "_id" : "a", "comment" : "Have a Nice Day" } }
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: well this is not exactly what i was seeking for still it is not merged to the main i guess theres no way to do that